# Bad boot error and superblock

Tags: crash, bios, reboot, badblocks

I was about to spend the next 3 hours playing CSGO, but the Steam client wouldn’t launch. I tried launching it from the command line interface, but there was an error saying that `~/.steam/error.log` was read-only. I then performed `chmod 666` on the file to yet again encounter the same error. Frustrated, I tried to open up Discord and I got a similar read-only file error bug. Then, I realized almost all my files were read-only, so I decided to restart my computer. Upon restarting, I found this 1st error.

[image: First error]

I therefore decided to go into my BIOS and turn `TMP state` to `disabled`. I then booted my computer up once again and found this 2nd error, which is where we are at now.

[image]

I am totally stumped as it looks like it seems to be a bad drive superblock and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: This is a support site, if this relates to a bug you should be on a bug tracker. All I see is an unclean file system which needs a check (file system check or `fsck`).  This is best performed by boot a 'live' system & running `fsck` from there (you don't want file system in use thus 'live' system makes it easy).  If errors are detected, the whole filesystem is flipped to RO (read-only) to prevent damage/data-loss which is probably what occurred at the start (but you ignored messages/warnings), and it preventative & not related to any bug.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured it out. First, I re-enabled TPM. Then, All I had to do was type in `fsck -f /dev/{corrupted device}`. This would fix everything by reorganizing the file system and dealing with the blocks.